# How to configure NLog for Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, nlog

I could really need some help.

I want to use NLog with Azure Functions v2 (Target Framework .NET Core 2.2) – and have created a

```
Startup : FunctionsStartup
```

class decorated with

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(PmsFunctions.Startup))]
```

And created this method

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
    {
        loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
        loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
        loggingBuilder.AddNLog();
    }).BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

In constructor of the Startup class I have created the configuration of NLog using code:

```
var mailTarget = new MailTarget("mandrill")
{

    Html = true,
    AddNewLines = true,
    ReplaceNewlineWithBrTagInHtml = true,
    Subject = "XXXXX",
    To = "john@doe.com,
    From = "john@doe.com",
    Body = "Message: ${message}${newline}${newline}Date: ${date}${newline}${newline}Exception: ${exception:format=tostring}${newline}${newline}",
    SmtpUserName = "XXXXXXX",
    SmtpPassword = "XXXXXXX",
    SmtpAuthentication = SmtpAuthenticationMode.Basic,
    SmtpServer = "XXXXXXXX",
    SmtpPort = 587
};

var bufferedMailTarget = new BufferingTargetWrapper("bufferedMandril", mailTarget)
{
    SlidingTimeout = false,
    BufferSize = 100,
    FlushTimeout = 10000
};
config.AddTarget(bufferedMailTarget);

var mailRule = new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Warn, bufferedMailTarget);
config.LoggingRules.Add(mailRule);

var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(config).GetCurrentClassLogger
```

I try to use the logger in the functons by using the injected ILogger. It works perfectly locally but it is completely “dead” when using Azure. I guess it is the way I configure the NLog.

How should I do it the right way?

Comment: Do you remember to flush before exit ? Good idea to call `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown()`

Comment: @RolfKristensen: Where would you call NLog.LogManager.Shutdown() in Azure Fuctions? Just so I do it right.

Comment: Well use try-catch-finally and put the `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown()` in the finally-block and error-logging in the catch-block. Maybe you want to perform and explicit call `NLog.LogManager.Flush()` before doing Shutdown() with extra long timeout (Ex. 60 secs). By default timeout is "only" 15 secs, which might not be enough for mail-smtp-call to finish.

Comment: Don't call `ClearProviders()` (this removes some internal logging -- we'll be preventing this soon) or `BuildServiceProvider()`. If this works locally but not on Azure, I suspect something in the App Service sandbox may be affecting you. I'll do some investigating and try to reproduce this.

Comment: Are you making sure to wait 10+ seconds for your flush? I was able to get it working (added an answer below so you can see my code exactly).

Comment: @RolfKristensen Your comment doesn't make much sense. Do you mean in every function handler or somewhere in the Startup class. If in the Startup class then where, I can't see an appropriate hook.

Comment: @GrahamB You should flush at the end of the Function-method that can trigger the logevent, that should reach the mail-target.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure NLog follows the lifetime of the Azure function, then you should configure it to shutdown (and flush) together with Microsoft-Extension-Logging:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        private readonly NLog.Logger Logger;

        public Startup()
        {
            Logger = LogManager.Setup()
               .SetupExtensions(e => e.AutoLoadAssemblies(false))
               .LoadConfigurationFromFile("NLog.config", optional: false)
               .LoadConfiguration(builder => builder.LogFactory.AutoShutdown = false)
               .GetCurrentClassLogger();
        }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // ... other setup code
            builder.Services.AddLogging((loggingBuilder) =>
            {
                var nlogOptions = new NLogProviderOptions() {
                    ShutdownOnDispose = true, 
                    RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter = true
                };
                loggingBuilder.AddNLog(nlogOptions);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Notice `ShutdownOnDispose = true` and `AutoShutdown = false`

Comment: You are repeating code from the NLog.Extensions.Logging docs. What is the purpose of the `Logger` field? How does it help? (and `readonly readonly` is a syntax error).

Comment: @TsahiAsher Have fixed the syntax error. The `Logger` is mostly for doing any logging before Microsoft `ILogger` is available.

Comment: Thanks. So if I don't need a logger in the Startup class, can I skip it? Or do I need the code at least to set `LogFactory.AutoShutdown = false`?

Comment: @TsahiAsher Yes the important part is `AutoShutdown = false` and `ShutdownOnDispose = true` to ensure LoggerFactory-lifetime handles shutdown (Disable NLog auto shutdown on AppDomain-shutdown). Microsoft introduced a bug in .Net5 where AppDomain-shutdown-event was triggered prematurely (Maybe it has been fixed with .Net6)

Answer (score -1):

I set mine up just like this and I'm successfully getting emails from my service in Azure (I set up one function to explicitly log a warning so when I call it, I get an email).

```
public Startup()
{
    LoggingConfiguration config = new LoggingConfiguration();

    var mailTarget = new MailTarget("mandrill")
    {
        Html = true,
        AddNewLines = true,
        ReplaceNewlineWithBrTagInHtml = true,
        Subject = "Test...",
        To = "-----",
        From = "john@doe.com",
        Body = "Message: ${message}${newline}${newline}Date: ${date}${newline}${newline}Exception: ${exception:format=tostring}${newline}${newline}",
        SmtpUserName = "-----",
        SmtpPassword = "-----",
        SmtpAuthentication = SmtpAuthenticationMode.Basic,
        SmtpServer = "-----",
        SmtpPort = 587
    };

    var bufferedMailTarget = new BufferingTargetWrapper("bufferedMandril", mailTarget)
    {
        SlidingTimeout = false,
        BufferSize = 100,
        FlushTimeout = 10000
    };

    config.AddTarget(bufferedMailTarget);

    var mailRule = new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Warn, bufferedMailTarget);
    config.LoggingRules.Add(mailRule);

    NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(config);
}

public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddLogging(b =>
    {
        b.AddNLog();
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use MicrosoftILoggerTarget:

```
var loggerTarget = new NLog.Extensions.Logging.MicrosoftILoggerTarget(azureILogger);
loggerTarget.Layout = new NLog.Layouts.Layout("${message}${exception:format=tostring}");  // Can also be JsonLayout
var nlogConfig = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();
nlogConfig.AddRuleForAllLevels(loggerTarget);
NLog.LogManager.Configuration = nlogConfig;
var nlogLogger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
nlogLogger.Info("Hello World");
```

Source: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-cloud-logging-with-Azure-function-or-AWS-lambda

Comment: This is actually for when you **don't** want to use NLog as a logging provider. This redirects the logs to the configured `ILogger`, which is not NLog's.