# Nlog in Azure functions not working when injected via DI

Tags: azure-functions, nlog

Reference Code taken from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56512672/how-to-configure-nlog-for-azure-functions#:~:text=0,and%20AutoShutdown%20%3D%20false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56512672/how-to-configure-nlog-for-azure-functions#:%7E:text=0,and%20AutoShutdown%20%3D%20false)

My StartUp.cs file

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using NLog;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(NLogFunctionApp.StartUp))]
namespace NLogFunctionApp
{
    public class StartUp :FunctionsStartup
    {
        private readonly NLog.Logger logger;
        public StartUp()
        {
            logger = LogManager.Setup()
                      .SetupExtensions(e=>e.AutoLoadAssemblies(false))
                        .LoadConfigurationFromFile("nlog.config", optional: false)
               .LoadConfiguration(builder => builder.LogFactory.AutoShutdown = false)
               .GetCurrentClassLogger();
        }
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder hostBuilder)
        {
            hostBuilder.Services.AddLogging((loggingBuilder) =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddNLog(new NLogProviderOptions() { ShutdownOnDispose = true });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

"NLogSample.cs function file"

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog;

namespace NLogFunctionApp
{
    public class NLogSample
    {
        private readonly ILogger<NLogSample> log;
        private static  Logger logCurrent;

        public NLogSample(ILogger<NLogSample> logger)
        {
            log = logger;
            logCurrent = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        }

        [FunctionName("NLogSample")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            logCurrent.Info("This is printing");
            log.LogInformation("This is not printing");
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

nlog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="https://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\jjgnet-functions-internal-nlog.log"
      internalLogLevel="Debug" >

  <variable name="logDirectory" value="${currentdir}${dir-separator}logs${dir-separator}" />
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.Logging"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget" />
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!--<target xsi:type="File" name="file-everything" fileName="${logDirectory}${shortdate}-everything.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${gdc:item=Version}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
    <target xsi:type="File" name="file-host" fileName="${logDirectory}${shortdate}-host.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${gdc:item=Version}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
    <target xsi:type="File" name="file-just-mine" fileName="${logDirectory}${shortdate}-just-mine.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${gdc:item=Version}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />-->

    <target xsi:type="ApplicationInsightsTarget" name="aiTarget">
      <instrumentationKey>AzureAppInsightkeyvalue</instrumentationKey>
      <!-- Only required if not using ApplicationInsights.config -->
      <contextproperty name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
      <contextproperty name="AssemblyVersion" layout="${gdc:item=ExecutingAssembly-AssemblyVersion}" />
      <contextproperty name="FileVersion" layout="${gdc:item=ExecutingAssembly-FileVersion}" />
      <contextproperty name="ProductVersion" layout="${gdc:item=ExecutingAssembly-ProductVersion}" />
    </target>

    <target xsi:type="Console" name="logconsole"
            layout="${longdate}|${level}|${logger}|${message} |${all-event-properties} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logconsole" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="aiTarget" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Code with "This is printing" is working fine but when injecting from DI it is not printing logs.
Some default logs are getting printed but not with log.LogInformation.

host.json is empty, no logging configs are there which are provided by default.

Could someone please help. Searched many where but could not find the reason.
GitHub repo link - https://github.com/jatingandhi28/NLogAzureFunctions

Comment: What happens if you change `LogInformation` to `LogError` ?

Comment: @RolfKristensen - Thanks for your reply, checked but to no avail. Added github repo link.

Comment: What happens if you replace `new NLogProviderOptions() { ShutdownOnDispose = true }` with `new NLogProviderOptions() { ShutdownOnDispose = true, RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter = true }`

Comment: @RolfKristensen Working like charm!! You are a gem! Another problem I'm facing when adding ApplicationInsightsTarget - it is not logging in Azure ApplicationInsights? Please post in answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @RolfKristensen Now AppInsights also working perfect. Thank You for you quick help. I will update code on Git repo in case someone needs help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to disable the filter-logic in Microsoft LoggerFactory by changing from:

```
new NLogProviderOptions() { ShutdownOnDispose = true }
```

To this

```
new NLogProviderOptions() { ShutdownOnDispose = true, RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter = true }
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Missing-trace%5Cdebug-logs-in-ASP.NET-Core-6%3F

Comment: The github link you have provided is adding configuration. In my case I have Azure function, if I add this config in my host.json then default logging will start and two logs will be printed. There is no way I could find to remove this logging, ClearProviders throws error in Azure functions.
I could not make sense of these configs?

Comment: @JatinGandhi I was just trying to highlight that the Microsoft LoggerFactory has builtin filtering. Not an expert on how to control the filtering for Azure-Functions. Besides that one can use `RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter` to turn off filtering for NLog.