# How to make .NET 6 Azure Functions V4 work with NLog with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-6.0, nlog

I've been working on this all day and looked at the NLog documentation, StackOverflow, and the NLog GitHub issues. However, there is no real example of how to make Azure Functions V4 work with NLog and correctly write to a database and .txt file in the solution folder. I'm only able to get it to log in the console when running locally.

I've noticed appsettings.json doesn't seem to function with NLog and Azure functions and you must create an nlog.config file or nlog.json file.

I've tried using both of these as references and neither actually gets my code to work.

[NLog in Azure Function Log Streams using nlog.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66357471/nlog-in-azure-function-log-streams-using-nlog-config)

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3538

Does anyone have an example of code that actually works with what must be put in the Startup.cs, the AzureFunctions.cs and appsettings.json file?

Comment: You can use [NLog.Extension.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging/) that supports loading [NLog configuration from appsettings.json](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/71037798/193178 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/56512672/193178 ?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out.

I used the Nuget packages...

```
NLog
NLog.Database
NLog.Extensions.Logging
NLog.Web.AspNetCore
```

Code in the Configure Method of my Startup.cs of my Azure Functions V4

```
var _logger = LogManager.Setup()
            .SetupExtensions(e => e.AutoLoadExtensions())
            .LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings(Path.Combine(builder.GetContext().ApplicationRootPath), null, "NLog", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .LoadConfiguration(builder => builder.LogFactory.AutoShutdown = false)
            .GetCurrentClassLogger();

builder.Services.AddLogging((loggingBuilder) =>
 { 
  var nlogOptions = new NLogProviderOptions()
  {
    ShutdownOnDispose = true,
    RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter = true
  };
  loggingBuilder.AddNLog(nlogOptions);
  });
```

In the ConfigureAppConfiguration I put...

```
var config = builder.ConfigurationBuilder
            .SetBasePath(context.ApplicationRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
```

Also the ILogger and ILoggerFactory section of this Microsoft page helped me understand how to dependency inject and edit the host.json file for it to work without passing the logger to other classes ran by the Azure Functions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

Basic example:

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using NLog;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();

            builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "appsettings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
                .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, $"appsettings.{context.EnvironmentName}.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder hostBuilder)
        {
            hostBuilder.Services.AddLogging((loggingBuilder) =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddNLog(new NLogProviderOptions() {
                    AutoShutdown = false,
                    ShutdownOnDispose = true,
                    RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter = true, 
                    LoggingConfigurationSectionName = "NLog"
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then just place [NLog-configuration in appsettings.json](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json). Alternative one can initialize NLog-configuration [from code using fluent api](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Configuration-API).

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection